# How to open file with IntelliJ IDEA in new tab with command line?

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I specify the file to open in new tab with IntelliJ IDEA via command line?

If I run in command line:

```
idea d:\Dropbox\Dropbox\featurea\featurea-common\src\com\featurea\common\util\FileManager.java
```

I get "No project found to open file in" error

[image: "No project found to open file in" error]

Open file in new tab with opened project also fails.

Is there any way to manage IntelliJ IDEA to behave as I want?

Thanks.

Comment: I already use IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.3
Build #IC-129.451, built on May 10, 2013

Comment: Your IDE is in some weird state, it's not on the welcome screen, but it also doesn't look like you have an open project, do you? For this feature to work you need to create/open a project first. You will see the project name and path in the window title, yours just shows `IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.3`. Probably you have a project without modules.

Comment: It's because I open it with command line `idea d:\Dropbox\Dropbox\featurea\featurea-common\src\com\featurea\common\util\FileManager.java`

Comment: You can't open files from the command line without already open project, it's by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't open individual files in the IDE from the command line when there is no open project and the IDE is not already running.

You can pass the project directory as an argument to open the project first, then you will be able to open individual files.

Comment: Could you please sclarify after I pass the project directory as an argument to open the project first, how then I will be able to open individual files? `idea d:\Dropbox\Dropbox\featurea\featurea-common\src\com\featurea\common\util\FileMan‌​ager.java` this does not work

Comment: When IDEA is started and there is a project already open, `idea d:\Dropbox\Dropbox\featurea\featurea-common\src\com\featurea\common\util\FileMan‌​‌​ager.java` works just fine. I've verified it on my Windows machine. File opens in the IDE.